# Not able to create object using DSA

Tags: opengl

This code works fine.

```
glGenVertexArrays(1, &m_VAO);
glGenBuffers(1, &m_VBO);
glGenBuffers(1, &m_EBO);
glBindVertexArray(m_VAO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_VBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, data.size()  * sizeof(VertexFormat), &data[0] , GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_EBO);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices.size() * sizeof(GL_UNSIGNED_INT), &indices[0], GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(VertexFormat), (void*)0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(VertexFormat), (void*)(3 * sizeof(float)));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(VertexFormat), (void*)(6 * sizeof(float)));
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

But when i try to change it to DSA nothing gets drawn on the screen.

```
glCreateBuffers(1, &m_VBO);
glNamedBufferStorage(m_VBO, data.size() * sizeof(VertexFormat), &data[0], GL_DYNAMIC_STORAGE_BIT);

glCreateBuffers(1, &m_EBO);
glNamedBufferStorage(m_EBO, indices.size() * sizeof(unsigned int), &indices[0], GL_DYNAMIC_STORAGE_BIT);

glCreateVertexArrays(1, &m_VAO);

glVertexArrayVertexBuffer(m_VAO, 0, m_VBO, 0, data.size() * sizeof(VertexFormat));
glVertexArrayElementBuffer(m_VAO, m_EBO);

glEnableVertexArrayAttrib(m_VAO, 0);
glEnableVertexArrayAttrib(m_VAO, 1);
glEnableVertexArrayAttrib(m_VAO, 2);

glVertexArrayAttribFormat(m_VAO, 0, 3 , GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0);
glVertexArrayAttribFormat(m_VAO, 1, 3 , GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0);
glVertexArrayAttribFormat(m_VAO, 2, 2 , GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0);

glVertexArrayAttribBinding(m_VAO, 0, 0);
glVertexArrayAttribBinding(m_VAO, 1, 0); 
glVertexArrayAttribBinding(m_VAO, 2, 0);
```

What is the issue in the DSA section of code?

Comment: How do you draw objects?

Comment: @Squid233 Issue is with the DSA section of the code , in non DSA version object gets drawn without issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not transfer over two pieces of information.

You didn't specify the stride in `glVertexArrayVertexBuffer` correctly. When using separate attribute format, a stride of 0 doesn't mean "tightly packed"; it means exactly what it says: zero bytes will be added to get the next array element.

You also didn't specify the offsets for each attribute in `glVertexArrayAttribFormat` the way you did with `glVertexAttribPointer`.